# How does absolute imports work with unrelated imports in sitecustomize.py?

Tags: python

I have a package with an unfortunately named module:

```
(dev) go|c:\srv\tmp\absimp> tree myapp
myapp
|-- __init__.py
|-- calendar.py
`-- tst.py
```

with contents

`__init__.py`: empty.

`myapp\calendar.py`:

```
from __future__ import print_function
print("imported:", __file__)
```

`myapp\tst.py` (the second line prints the current working directory (cwd) and all directories under cwd that are on python's module search path:

```
from __future__ import print_function, absolute_import
import sys,os; cwd=os.getcwd(); print("CWD:", cwd, "PATH:", [p for p in sys.path if p.startswith(cwd)])

import calendar
print("CALENDAR from myapp/tst:", calendar.__file__)
```

`myapp\tst.py` wants to import the Python's global `calendar` module, so I've enabled `absolute_import` and not imported it as `from . import calendar`.

Standing outside of the myapp directory I still get the local `calendar.py` (Pythons 2.7.16 and 3.8.0 - output is identical):

```
(dev) go|c:\srv\tmp\absimp> python myapp\tst.py
CWD: c:\srv\tmp\absimp PATH: ['c:\\srv\\tmp\\absimp\\myapp']
imported: c:\srv\tmp\absimp\myapp\calendar.py
CALENDAR from myapp/tst: c:\srv\tmp\absimp\myapp\calendar.py
```

From the first output line I see that Python has added the `tst.py`'s directory to `sys.path`.

If I edit my `sitecustomize.py` file, adding

```
import _strptime
```

and re-run the above command, I now get the global `calendar`...:

```
(dev) go|c:\srv\tmp\absimp> python myapp\tst.py
CWD: c:\srv\tmp\absimp PATH: ['c:\\srv\\tmp\\absimp\\myapp']
CALENDAR from myapp/tst: c:\python27\Lib\calendar.pyc
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works because [`_strptime`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b138dd296a206e92ebec09b540bb88a1539563e4/Lib/_strptime.py#L15) imports `calendar` itself, even before the main script's path is put on the `PATH`, since you specify that import in `sitecustomize.py` (these imports are done beforehand). Now `calendar` is already in the module cache and so it won't be imported a second time, but the one from the cache will be reused:

```
>>> import sys
>>> 'calendar' in sys.modules
False
>>> import _strptime
>>> 'calendar' in sys.modules
True
```

---

In fact it doesn't matter what type of object is stored in `sys.modules` it will be matched by the module's name as the key. For example:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.modules['calendar'] = 'foo'
>>> import calendar
>>> print(calendar)
foo
```

Comment: Are you saying that Python still thinks that `myapp/calendar.py` is the "global" `calendar`, but it also thinks that the `calendar` module has already been loaded?

Comment: Python imports packages by searching `sys.path` in order and uses whatever it finds, unless a module with the same name already exists in `sys.modules` (the module cache). So there is no notion of "global" or "local", it just searches the path. When you run a script, the script's directory will be put at index 0 in `sys.path`. However imports done in `sitecustomize.py` are done beforehand, so here `calendar` will be found as part of the stdlib. Then when you import `calendar` it will be loaded from `sys.modules` instead.